# main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

```
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
     {
         $request = $this->_appRequestInterface->getPost(); 
            
          try
          {
              if($this->_configScopeConfigInterface->getValue('minqty/general/enabled', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,$this->_modelStoreManagerInterface->getStore())) :
            
              $main_product_id = 0;
              if(array_key_exists('super_group',$request) && array_key_exists('product',$request))
              {
                  $main_product_id = $request['product'];
                  $main_product = $this->_modelProductFactory->create()->load($main_product_id);
                  $allowed_qty = $main_product->getCustomminqty();
                   
                  if($allowed_qty > 0 && $allowed_qty != '')
                  {     
                      $total_qty = 0;
                      foreach($request['super_group'] as $cur_qty)
                      {
                          if($cur_qty != '')
                          {
                              $total_qty = $total_qty + $cur_qty;
                          }
                      }
                        
                      if($total_qty < $allowed_qty)
                      {  
                          $message = "The minimum quantity allowed for purchase is ".$allowed_qty.".";
                          throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($message));
                          return;
                      }
                  }
              }
              endif;
          }
          catch(Exception $e)
          {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage())); 
            return;
          }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP 7.4 the function `array_key_exists` allows only `array` and doesn't support `ArrayObject` anymore

The method `getPost` from Request returns `\Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters` which extends from `ArrayObject`

You can use `Parameters` method `toArray` to receive array or use `offsetExists` instead of `array_key_exists`

```php
$postArray = $this->_appRequestInterface->getPost()->toArray();
array_key_exists('key', $postArray);

// or
$post = $this->_appRequestInterface->getPost();
$post->offsetExists('key');
```